Telegram bot with postgresql and asyncpg. Error during DB query execution: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send
I have telegram bot and database on postgresql. Database There is a pic of it.
My database works properly and if i need to add something in it or smth, it works.
I need functions that can add subscription for someone and get subscription.
Function for adding subscription
async def add_subscription(user_id: BigInteger, start_date: DateTime, end_date: DateTime):
    async with async_session() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            new_subscription = UserSubscription(
                user_id=user_id,
                subscription_start=start_date,
                subscription_end=end_date
            )
            session.add(new_subscription)
            await session.commit()

Function for getting subscription
async def get_subscription(user_id: BigInteger):
    async with async_session() as session:
        print(f"Running DB query for user_id: {user_id}")
        async with session.begin():
            print("session begins")
            try:
                query = text("SELECT subscription_start, subscription_end FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id")
                result = await session.scalars(query, {"user_id": user_id})
                subscription = result._fetchone_impl()
                return subscription
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error during DB query execution: {e}")
                return None

I added a lot of prints to try to understand where the error is. 2nd function(get_subscription i mean) i face print("session begins"), then i face error. It says:
session begins
2024-09-04 01:08:52,132 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:BEGIN (implicit)
2024-09-04 01:08:52,133 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT subscription_start, subscription_end FROM users WHERE user_id = $1
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:SELECT subscription_start, subscription_end FROM users WHERE user_id = $1
2024-09-04 01:08:52,134 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 21.7s ago] (1867377574,)
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:[cached since 21.7s ago] (1867377574,)
Error during DB query execution: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
2024-09-04 01:08:52,135 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
INFO:sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:COMMIT
Subscription: None

1867377574 : MY TG ID.

I created a command in my bot named "/subscription". My code is :
@dp.message(Command("subscription"))
async def cmd_subscription(message: types.Message):
    print("Command /subscription received") 
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    print(f"User ID: {user_id}")
    try:
        subscription = await db.get_subscription(user_id)
        print(f"Subscription: {subscription}")  # Выводим полученные данные
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving subscription: {e}")  # Выводим ошибку, если что-то пошло не так
        return  # Прерываем выполнение, если есть ошибка
    
    if subscription:
        start_date, end_date = subscription
        response = f"Subscription Start: {start_date}\nSubscription End: {end_date}"
    else:
        response = "No subscription found for your user ID."
    
    try:
        await message.answer(response)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error sending message: {e}")  # Выводим ошибку, если не удаётся отправить сообщение

So, when i get to the bot and write command /subscription, it says No subscription found for your user ID and gives me an error Error during DB query execution: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send.
I don't get any further than subscription = await db.get_subscription(user_id), so problem is in 2nd function (get_subscription) or database connect idk.
I have this in the end of the code, it might be useful
async def main():
    
    # Получение подписки
    subscription = await get_subscription(user_id=1867377574)
    print(subscription)

# Запуск основного асинхронного цикла
asyncio.run(main())


Okay i found the solution. i didn't add if name == "main":
asyncio.run(main()).
I thought it has to be in Bot.py file, but not in database.py file.

Okay i found the solution. i didn't add if name == "main": asyncio.run(main()). I thought it has to be in Bot.py file, but not in database.py file.
